# sum value of selected cells in stringgrid

Tags: delphi

How can I get the sum value of the selected cells or a range in `stringgrid`? Please note that  sometimes these cells contain string values!

I try `GridCoord`, but it doesn't work good because sometimes there are "hidden columns".

```
procedure TMainShowForm.StgSelectionChanged(Sender: TObject; ALeft, ATop,
 ARight, ABottom: Integer);
var
i: Integer;
gc: TGridCoord;
sum:double;
begin
  for i := 1 to stg.SelectedCellsCount do
    begin
      gc := stg.SelectedCell[i - 1];
      sum:=sum+stg.floats[(gc.X),(gc.Y)];
    end;
  AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:='Sum = '+ formatfloat('#,##0.',sum);
  AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[1].Text:='Count = '+ inttostr(stg.SelectedCellsCount);
end;
```

Comment: What is `stg` in your code, is that `TAdvStringGrid` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***How to get sum of the floating-point values of a selection in TStringGrid ?***

For standard Delphi [`TStringGrid`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid) for instance this way:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Sum: Double;
  Val: Double;
  Col: Integer;
  Row: Integer;
begin
  Sum := 0;
  for Col := StringGrid1.Selection.Left to StringGrid1.Selection.Right do
    for Row := StringGrid1.Selection.Top to StringGrid1.Selection.Bottom do
      if TryStrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[Col, Row], Val) then
        Sum := Sum + Val;
  ShowMessage('Sum of the selection is ' + FloatToStr(Sum) + '.');
end;
```

***How to get sum of the floating-point values of a selection (including invisible cells) in TAdvStringGrid ?***

Hence you're most probably using [`TAdvStringGrid`](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advgrid.asp) you can try the following not yet tested or optimized code. So far I found, you can use `AllFloats` property to access all grid cells as float irrespective of hidden columns or rows. Assuming you want to sum continuous selection after you hide a certain column, you may try this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Sum: Double;
  Col: Integer;
  Row: Integer;
begin
  Sum := 0;
  for Col := AdvStringGrid1.Selection.Left to AdvStringGrid1.Selection.Right do
    for Row := AdvStringGrid1.Selection.Top to AdvStringGrid1.Selection.Bottom do
      Sum := Sum + AdvStringGrid1.AllFloats[Col, Row];
  ShowMessage('Sum of the selection is ' + FloatToStr(Sum) + '.');
end;
```

Comment: it's work good but not for the case when u have hidden col or row in the grid

Comment: I haven't paid enough attention to the example you've posted. Sure, it works just because I'm lucky and because TMS Software kept this part of the control same as the standard Delphi VCL. Code from my post is for `TStringGrid`, but you're talking about another control, most probably `TAdvStringGrid`.